# React Native Webview - Opening same URL even after updating via state

Tags: android, ios, react-native, progressive-web-apps, react-native-webview

I'm facing issue react-native-webview . The issue is like opening app initial I have set URL in state but when the new URL comes up from push notification then its not updating the webview even after updating the state.

Please help me if any one has the solution for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `reference` for `webview` like given below and call
`webViewRef.reload()`, when you want to reload the webview

```
<WebView 
 ref={(ref) => {
          this.webViewRef = ref
        }} 
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way, by adding a timestamp to URL

```
      this.setState({
        url: DEFAULT_URL + '?t='+ Date.now()
      });
```